# Remove all "Allow From All" from servers .htaccess

Tags: bash, .htaccess, sed

I have shell access to a web server that is being used for staging sites.  Needless to say, there are a ton of "staging" websites on it.

The paths are like: `/home/ACCOUNT/public_html` and we have set a global `htpasswd` to "restrict" access (mainly from being spidered by google...)

What I am finding is my "team" of developers insist on adding an `Allow From All` to the site's .htaccess file while they are working on the site, and forget to take it out again.

How can I remove that line?  Note, it can be any sort of letter case.. I've even seen `alLow frOm ALl`

I thought `sed` could do it, and I can just simply loop the directories to find the necessary .htaccess files, but I am a bit `sed` illiterate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like, starting with topmost directory:

```
find . -name '.htaccess' | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\s*allow\s+from\s+all\s*//i'
```

Replace `-pi` by  `-pi.bak` if you want to retain a backup file (recommended)

The `find`will take care of recursing into all subdirectories, the `xargs` will run the following command for each match and the `perl` command is similar to `sed` the whole regex replacement in `s///` will match all `allow from all` combinations depending on the number of spaces and tabs. The final `/i` makes sure it is done case-insensitively.

I recommend you to create a directory, put some `.htaccess` files there and run the command to try it before trying it to your live files.

Comment: tested.  doesn't seem to work, as I still have items like `Allow fRom AlL` that exists... in fact, even normal cased exist

Comment: @Kevin fixed by removing the anchoring.

Comment: yep, that did the trick, tho I don't see what the differences were lol
Thanks for the help with this... I ended up changing that `find` a bit because I have to loop through these directories for a seperate task anyways :)

Comment: After a couple of days with this running as a cronjob, I have found that in some circumstances, it not only deleted the line, it clears the entire .htaccess file out, making this method useless

Comment: I am certain it does not do what you say. Except if there was only that line in the file. Or if you changes things from what is written above.

Comment: And I am 100% positive it does exactly what I stated.    Any .htaccess file that had a `Allow From All` line, is now completely blank

Comment: Not because of the line above. Easy to prove. Create a file with whatever lines you want in it plus an allow from, run the snippet above, observe the file after. I just did and it works as expected. So show your proofs.